# Como corrigir problemas com site responsivo ao redirecionar a janela do navegador no DESKTOP?

Tags: javascript, layout-responsivo

Estou criando um site responsivo, ao redirecionar o tamanho da janela no DESKTOP alguns ajustes vão sendo feito e ao RETORNAR ao tamanho normal (maximizar) os ajustes retornar. Até aí tudo Ok.

O problema está no MENU e em parte do site mas eu vou mostrar um exemplo mais simples e de fácil compreensão abaixo que ocorre erro no site ok.

Eu tenho o seguinte:

TITULO
CHAMADA
Conteúdo

Nesse caso o título está em h1 a chamada em h2 e o conteúdo em h3 (este no caso está dentro de uma  que eu vou explicar o porque daqui a pouco).

Quando visualizamos no DESKTOP tudo é exigido direto pois temos espaço para isso, mas quando é exibido em uma tela menor (smartphone ou tablet) a ideia seria 'ocultar' a div que está com o h3 e só exibir se o usuário solicitar. Sendo assim colocamos um botão então para executar isso.

TITULO
CHAMADA
**botão para exibir conteúdo**
Conteúdo

O PROBLEMA é o seguinte:

Se diminuir o tamanho da janela o CONTEÚDO some e ao aumentar novamente o CONTEÚDO aparece. Tudo CORRETO, porém, se eu diminuir o tamanho da janela, posso clicar no botão para exibir o conteúdo lembra? Isso acontece com um efeito em jQuery para dar um SLIDE.

Ao clicar no botão o CONTEÚDO aparece e ao clicar no botão novamente o CONTEÚDO 'some' novamente com o efeito slide, perfeito. agora se eu maximizar a janela o CONTEÚDO simplesmente não aparece... ele continua oculto (porque ele sumiu devido ao SLIDE do jquery e não devido ao display:none do CSS então mesmo que o CSS diga que agora ele tem o display:block novamente ele não aparece...)

Mas eu já vi muitos sites com esse tipo de efeito, como por exemplo no MENU, eu tenho um MENU no topo do site inline mas que ao redirecionar ele muda (para lista e fica fixo ao lado direito).

Até aí ok... porém nesse processo eu aplico o display: none também e ele só aparece se clicar no 'botão menu' como qualquer site faz.

Se eu clico o MENU aparece com slide e pode ser fechado que também vai ser feito por SLIDE do jquery mas agora se aumentar a janela cadê o MENU inline do topo? Mesmo que volte o display:block devido ao width especificado no CSS como o MENU sumiu com o efeito SLIDE ele não aparece mais (só se eu diminuir a janela, abrir o MENU e então maximizar a janela denovo agora ele volta ao normal mas isso está esquisito sei lá).

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso pessoal?

Eu acho que o ideal seria NÃO utilizar o SLIDE do jquery para fazer aparece e sumir, mas então como fazer isso?

Muito obrigado.

HTML

```
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<h2>O que é Lorem Ipsum?</h2>

<input class="btn" type="button" value="Mostrar/Esconder" onclick="conteudo();">

<div id="conteudo" class="conteudo">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</h3>
</div>
```

CSS para esconder o CONTEÚDO ao redimensionar a janela

```
.btn {display: none}
.conteudo {display: block}

@media screen and (max-width:640px){
.conteudo {display: none;}
.btn {display: block}
}
```

JS utilizado para 'linkar' o JQUERY e poder usar o efeito em questão.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

JS utilizado para mostrar/ocultar o CONTEUDO quando estiver com exibição 'mobile'.

```
<script>    
var slide = 'slide';
var optionsSlideUp = { direction: "up" };
function conteudo(){$('#conteudo').toggle(slide, optionsSlideUp, 500);}
</script>
```

Se o efeito SLIDE não for utilizado tudo funciona bem, o CONTEUDO fica com display: none com janela pequena e volta a ficar com display: block ao maximizar... porém se usar o efeito SLIDE ocorre isso, mesmo maximizando ele não volta.

Comment: Cara, tua pergunta tem MUITO texto, pouco código e nenhum exemplo do que não está funcionando.
Tá bem difícil de entender o que tu preciso ou de ler até o final.

Comment: Olá Fernando, realmente coloquei muito texto pois é difícil explicar isso, não vi outra forma. Quanto ao código é que é algo relativamente simples, era só para mostrar/esconder o menu conforme o tamanho da tela do usuário.

Isso funcionou mas se eu usar um efeito tipo SLIDE o conteúdo some e não volta mais ao aumentar a tela.

Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código HTML para ver se assim fica mais fácil de entender sei lá, mas acho que isso em si é o de menos, o é complicado é saber porque o SLIDE impede a div de ficar visível novamente.

Comment: Pronto! Códigos agora estão na pergunta, coloquei tudo para poder até testar se quiser... html, css e JS, se só ficar redimensionando a janela vai ver que funciona legal, mas se tentar usar o botão (quando a janela estiver 'pequena' vai ver o problema que estou tendo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque a função `$.toggle` aplica uma animação e no final desta animação adiciona `display: none;` ao `style` do elemento que ela animou.

Então o que está acontecendo é que depois de esconder o conteúdo tua `div` fica dessa maneira: `<div id="conteudo" style="display: none;">`.

Por isso não está mais mostrando. Tu pode arrumar isso de duas maneiras diferentes, por CSS ou JS.

**CSS** (Aconselhável)

```css
@media screen and (min-width:640px){
    .conteudo {
        display: block; !important
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira quando tua `div` estiver em "tela grande" estará sempre com `display: block`.

**JS** (Nope):

```js
var $document = $(document),
    $conteudo = $("#conteudo");

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  if ($document.width() > 640) {
    $conteudo.show()
  }
});
```

**OBS**: Estou deixando esse exemplo apenas caso a solução com CSS não resolva teu problema. Porém deixo a advertência de que esse código não está otimizado e se for usá-lo pesquise primeiro sobre [throttle e debounce de eventos javascript](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/09/24/throttle-e-debounce-patterns-em-javascript/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo retorno meu amigo... mas infelizmente nenhum dos 2 casos deu certo...

O primeiro inclusive eu já havia feito mas não funcionou... o segundo eu testei agora e nada também... ela continua sem aparecer...

Estou usando o Google Chrome aqui e continua o erro =/